# Not able to send email to Gmail or Any other account except my organization account using Graph API? What to change to send mail to other domains?

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api

I am able to send email using following article:
https://jatindersingh81.medium.com/send-email-using-microsoft-graph-api-using-c-a838d128bb27
But only to my organization mail account, what to change to send mail to Gmail, outlook accounts.

Answer (score 0):

You can send email work or school account by using Delegated [Permission](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) type instead of using Application permission.
[image]

Please refer the below link for further details:

.[Microsoft Graph permissions reference| MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference).

.[Send outlook message from another user |MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-send-mail-from-other-user) .